# Convergence/Divergence of a particular infinite nested radical

Tags: elementary-number-theory, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

Is it known if the following infinite nested radical converges or diverges (for $n \in \mathbb N$)?:
$$R(n) = \sqrt{n+\sqrt{(n+1)+\sqrt{(n+2)+ \cdots}}}$$

I recently became interested in these problems when reading about Ramanujan's (famous?) formula: $$\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{\cdots}}}} = 3$$ Which he showed to be a special case of: $$\sqrt{ax+(n+a)^2+x\sqrt{a(x+n)+(n+a)^2+(x+n)\sqrt{\cdots}}} = x+n+a$$

My formula does not fit into that of Ramanujan and the farthest I am able to get is:
$$R^2(n) = n + R(n+1)$$ which I prefer to rewrite as $$R(n+1) = R^2(n) - n$$

This is well...not far at all.  Knowing $R(0)$ would supply me with all values of $R(n)$ and so I end up needing to solve $$\sqrt{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+ \sqrt{3+\cdots}}}}$$
I feel that the general method for solving these problems is currently beyond me without any instruction.  Would anyone be able to offer hints and get me a little bit further down the path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define
$$
S(n,m)=\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+1+\sqrt{n+2+\dots+\sqrt{m-1+\sqrt{m}}}}}\tag{1}
$$
Note that for $m\ge n\ge1$, we have $S(n,m)\ge1$ and
$$
\sqrt{n+x}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{n+x}+\sqrt{n}}\tag{2}
$$
Suppose that $S(n+1,m)\le\sqrt{n+1}+1$. Then by $(2)$,
$$
\begin{align}
S(n,m)
&=\sqrt{n+S(n+1,m)}\\[6pt]
&=\sqrt{n}+\frac{S(n+1,m)}{\sqrt{n+S(n+1,m)}+\sqrt{n}}\\
&\le\sqrt{n}+\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+1}{\sqrt{n+1}+1}\\[9pt]
&=\sqrt{n}+1\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Since $S(m,m)=\sqrt{m}\le\sqrt{m}+1$ for all $m$, we have shown that for $m\ge n\ge1$,
$$
S(n,m)\le\sqrt{n}+1\tag{4}
$$
For a given $n$, $S(n,m)$ is an increasing sequence in $m$ that is bounded above by $\sqrt{n}+1$, therefore its limit exists and
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}S(n,m)\le\sqrt{n}+1\tag{5}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I just have one question about the step where you assume $S(n+1,m) \leq \sqrt{n+1}+1$.  How does this work?  Is there something about induction with two variables that I am not getting (similar to Calvin's post?)

Comment: No, I am showing that $S(n+1,m)\le\sqrt{n+1}+1\implies S(n,m)\le\sqrt{n}+1$. That combined with the fact that $S(m,m)\le\sqrt{m}+1$ proves the assertion for all $n\le m$.

Comment: Ahhhh the lightbulb just went off. Thank you for the clear explanation. I think it is interesting that adding a variable $m$ helps to simplify the problem.

Comment: Unless we have some way to handle the infinite case, we need to limit ourselves to the finite case. Thus, some $m$ is needed. Then we can handle the infinite case by letting $m\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

If you accept
$$
\phi=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\cdots}}}}=\sqrt{1+\phi}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
\phi < R(1) &< \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2^2+\sqrt{2^4+\sqrt{2^8+\cdots}}}}}\\
&=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}\phi}
\end{align}
$$
so
$1.615<R(1)<1.815$ and as you say you can get the other $R(n)$ from there.

**Edit:** You can use this technique for any $n$:
$$
\phi_n=\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{\cdots}}}}=\sqrt{n+\phi_n}=\frac{1+\sqrt{4n+1}}{2} \\
\phi_n < R(n) < \sqrt{n+\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}\phi_n} \\
n+\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{n+\frac{1}{4}} < R^2(n) < n+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{n+\frac{5}{4}+\frac{1}{4n}}
$$

Comment: Very nice. Are there any hopes you think of finding an exact value for $R(n)$? Really we just need one, any one, and we have them all.