# Possible values of infinitely nested square root $n= \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}......}}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

If $$n= \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}......}}}$$ 
Is it possible that $n$ is a integer for any $x=Z( \text{zahlen number})$.If yes .What is the value of $x$??

Answer (score 9):

So, $n^2=x+n\iff n^2-x-n=0\implies n=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4x}}2$

As $n\ge0,n=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}2$ So, we need $1+4x$ to be Perfect Square

As $1+4x$ is odd, $1+4x=(2m+1)^2\iff x=m^2+m$ where $m$ is any integer

Comment: I think it should be $n=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4x}}2$

Comment: @user109899, Thanks for your observation. I was just thinking on my way

Comment: Well done, as expected! My nitpicking core wants to include a proof for the fact that the sequence defined by those nested square roots converges for these choices of $x$. Otherwise the equation $n^2=x+n$ loses its footing :-) This may have been covered elsewhere on the site?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Good Observation. Till I've found http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61048/definition-of-convergence-of-a-nested-radical-sqrta-1-sqrta-2-sqrta-3 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410413/convergence-divergence-of-a-particular-infinite-nested-radical  also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadical.html

Comment: That settles my doubts, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible and I think the value of $x= 0$.